# What does the error "bad argument to 'OutputLogMessage' (number expected, got nil)" mean?

Tags: lua, lazy-evaluation, logitech-gaming-software

I get an error stating:

```
[string "LuaVM"]:163: bad argument #3 to 'OutputLogMessage' (number expected, got nil) Line Number:1
LOADED
[string "LuaVM"]:163: bad argument #3 to 'OutputLogMessage' (number expected, got nil) Line Number:1
```

What does the error mean and what do I need to fix?

```lua
function mode_change(event, arg)
    ---one_ NO RECOIL
    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
    one_    = not one_
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 2) then
    two_    = not two_
    one_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
    three_  = not three_
    one_    = false
    two_    = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
    four_   = not four_
    one_    = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
    five_   = not five_
    one_    = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 6) then
    six_    = not six_
    one_    = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
    seven_  = not seven_
     one_   = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
    eight_  = not eight_
     one_   = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 9) then
    nine_   = not nine_
    one_    = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 10) then
    ten_    = not ten_
     one_   = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    eleven_ = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 11) then
    eleven_ = not eleven_
     one_   = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    twelve_ = false
    elseif (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 12) then
    twelve_ = not twelve_
     one_   = false
    two_    = false
    three_  = false
    four_   = false
    five_   = false
    six_    = false
    seven_  = false
    eight_  = false
    nine_   = false
    ten_    = false
    eleven_ = false
    end
end
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
            EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
            ReleaseMouseButton(2)
 
    end
    mode_change(event, arg)
    ---For Setting F1~F12 Key
    ---NO RECOIL SETTINGS (You can edit Sleep time and X,Y of NO RECOIL)
 
    ---one_ SETTINGS
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and one_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if one_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 8)
    Sleep(10)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---two_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and two_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if two_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 5)
    Sleep(10)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---three_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and three_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if three_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 7)
    Sleep(9)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---four_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and four_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if four_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 5)
    Sleep(8)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---five_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and five_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if five_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(1, 10)
    Sleep(7)
    MoveMouseRelative(-1, 1)
    Sleep(8)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---six_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and six_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if six_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(1, 10)
    Sleep(9)
    MoveMouseRelative(-1, 1)
    Sleep(8)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---seven_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and seven_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if seven_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(1, 10)
    Sleep(10)
    MoveMouseRelative(-1, 0)
    Sleep(8)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---eight_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and eight_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if eight_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 6)
    Sleep(15)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---nine_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and nine_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if nine_ then
    repeat
            PressKey("P")
            MoveMouseRelative(0,9)
            Sleep(30)
            ReleaseKey("P")    
            Sleep(50)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
 
    ---ten_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and ten_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if ten_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 6)
    Sleep(9)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---eleven_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and eleven_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    if eleven_ then
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0, 6)
    Sleep(11)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
 
    ---twelve_ SETTINGS
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and twelve_ and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    return
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The *printf*-style `OutputLogMessage` requires that the arguments associated with the `%d` *format specifier* (and other numeric specifiers) be a number type (or be coercible to a number type - i.e., producing a non-*nil* value from [`tonumber`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tonumber)).

This function directly mirrors the [`string.format`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format) function, which can be easily tested:

```lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> string.format('%d', 42)
42
> string.format('%d', '42')
42
> string.format('%d', nil)
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'format' (number expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'string.format'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
> string.format('%d')
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'format' (no value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'string.format'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

During the `"PROFILE_ACTIVATED"` and `"PROFILE_DEACTIVATED"`, `OnEvent` is passed a *nil* value as its second argument, and you are unconditionally passing it to `OutputLogMessage` as the argument associated with `%d`.

You can guard against this in a few ways, including

```lua
-- check that arg is truthy, choosing to display nothing if it is falsy (nil)
if arg then
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
end
```

or

```lua
-- display a truthy arg, or a sentinel value otherwise
OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg or -1)
```

---

As an aside, your `mode_change` is poor from a maintainability standpoint. Any time you find yourself enumerating variable names (lit. `var_one`, `var_two`, `var_three`, etc.) you should stop and ask yourself if there is not a more appropriate *data structure* to use.

In Lua you have access to [tables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2).

Consider the following, condensed example where any time a G-button is pressed, `keymap` is reassigned to a new table, effectively setting all possible values of `arg` to *nil*, except for the current value of *arg* being set to the inverse of its previous value.

(*nil is falsy, equivalent to `false` for the purpose of conditional logic (`if not x then`, etc.).*)

Current values can be checked through indexing the table (i.e. `keymap[4]`, `keymap[2]`, etc.).

```lua
local keymap = {}

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if "G_PRESSED" == event then
        keymap = { [arg] = not keymap[arg] }
    end

    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and keymap[1] then
        -- ...
    end
end
```

Comment: `During the "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" and "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED", OnEvent is passed a nil value as its second argument` - On my PC, zero is passed as `arg`.

Comment: I've updated GHub.  Indeed, in version 2023.7 `nil` is passed.

Comment: @Oka I'm fairly new to lua bit have a somewhat understanding of coding in general. Perhaps you can help me out & yes I agree tables would be better but that will be my next project to understand .

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, I should replace the line function onevent (event, arg) OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    To if arg then
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
end  . Or OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg or -1) after function onevent (event, arg) ?

Comment: @HasanRaqib - Try `OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, tostring(arg))`

Comment: Yes, either wrap the existing line containing the call to `OutputLogMessage` with an `if` statement that checks that `arg` is not nil. Or replace the line with the second example. Or come up with a different solution, if something else works better. You just have to make sure that a *nil* value isn't being passed to  `OutputLogMessage` when a number is expected - it doesn't have to be exactly the code I've shown. (You do not need to change the line `function OnEvent(event, arg)`.)

Comment: You guys are great, thanks so much it worked! Oka, if possible do you have any reference material to tables and an example script? that would help alot in learning LUA. @Eski thank man it works .. if u guys have any type of video or reference material to share that would be great for me (as i am still learrning) thank you

Comment: The book *Programming in Lua* is a good starting point. [Here is the chapter on tables.](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html)